# Unable to get IP address from hosted dhcp

Tags: linux, networking, mac-osx, dhcp

I have setup my Mac OS X server as a DHCP server and it is working fine. Now I have just connected a second switch to my old one (both gigabit) but the people who connect to the new switch are sometimes unable to get a IP address. What seems to be the problem?

Also, I have noticed that this problem goes away when i use a router as a dhcp server.

Any solutions???

Comment: "Sometimes"? Is the problem intermittent?

Comment: Are these managed switches, and are you using multiple VLANs if they are?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check whether there are enough IP addresses available in DHCP pool?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out your firewall settings DHCP is a layer 7 protocol, requests are on UDP port 68, replies on UDP 67. You will need port 68 open your server, 67 on the client